# How to create containers running the same mysql database via docker swarm?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a cluster with 2 nodes and 2 containers of the same database using docker swarm to practice. I first created the volume, network and started the cluster:

```
docker volume create $service_volume
docker network create --driver overlay --scope global $network_name
docker swarm init
```

Then, I am trying to create the replicas of the database to, after that, insert another node in the cluster and divide the load and sync files via NFS.

I tried to use a docker compose file as followed:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  mysql_service:
    image: mysql:latest
    replicas: 2
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    networks:
      - mysql_network
    volumes:
      - mysql_volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

but the service can't be created because of the error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.mysql_service: 'replicas'
```

then I tried to create the service directly by:

```
docker service create --name mysql_service --replicas 2 --network mysql_network --env MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 --mount type=volume,src=mysql_volume,dst=/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

The service is created, but the new database is not created inside of mysql_volume and when a try to connect do sys.db (which comes with the image) through dbeaver I receive an error:

```
null,  message from server: "Host '10.0.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

I really don't know if what I trying to do isn't supposed to be done or there is another way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is :10.0.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
Not that it doesn't exist .. its not allowed .. so allow it.  That or run Dbeaver from the localhost.

Comment: but I entered the volume of the container by path /var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql_volume/_data there is no testdb inside. When I was working with just one container it appeared.

Comment: Well it might not be there, but the error is saying it was denied ..and thus probably why it wasn't in the container.  Just pointing out the cause of the fail is "host not allowed" so that should be the focus I would think.

Comment: Although now that I am looking at this again .. the original issue is this:
"Unsupported config option " which in this case was "replicas" so I would start there and make sure that you have that option correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems trying to run replicated `mysql`.
Publishing a port attaches service tasks to swarms ingress network, which will load balance requests across replicas. Now I am not familiar with mysql, but I presume you need to explicitly connect to one, or the other instance, to setup clustering.

One way to deal with this is to use host mode networking.

first, mark two docker swarm nodes as the two nodes you want to run mysql instances on:

```bash
docker node update --label-add mysql=true node1
docker node update --label-add mysql=true node2
```

Then, deploy mysql using a compose.yml something like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

networks:
  public:
    name: mysql_public
    attachable: true
    external: false

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
    networks:
    - public
    ports:
    - mode: host
      published: 3306
      target: 3306
    volumes:
    - /mnt/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
        constraints:
        - node.labels.mysql==true
```

With this approach, you explicitly connect to node1 or node2 to access the two difference mysql instances.

Also, as the hosts that are running mysql are labeled, it's possible to  cater for persistent storage on the nodes directly, which I find safer than docker volumes for critical data, as docker volumes are a little too easy to prune.